# how to prove that multiplication of points of an elliptic curve can be done with division polynomials

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm trying to solve an exercise in the book The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves by Joseph H. Silverman on the page 106.
The exercise asks to prove that \begin{equation}
  nP=\left( x-\frac{\psi_{n-1}\psi_{n+1}}{\psi_{n}^2},\frac{\psi_{n+2}\psi_{n-1}^2-\psi_{n-2}\psi_{n+1}^2}{4y \psi_n^3}\right)
 \end{equation}
where 
P is a point of an elliptic curve E given by $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and
\begin{align*}
 \psi_0 & =0\\
 \psi_1 & =1\\
 \psi_2 & =2y\\
 \psi_3 & =3x^4+6ax^2+12bx-a^2\\
 \psi_4 & =4y(x^6+5ax^4+20bx^3-5a^2x^2-4abx-8b^2-a^3)\\
 \psi_{2m+1} & =\psi_{m+2}\psi_{m}^3-\psi_{m-1}\psi_{m+1}^3 \ \ m\geqslant2\\
 \psi_{2m} & =(2y)^{-1}(\psi_m)(\psi_{m+2}\psi_{m-1}^2-\psi_{m-2}\psi_{m+1}^2)  \ m\geqslant3\\
\end{align*}
Does anyone have an idea how to prove this? I tried to do some kind of recursive reasoning however I did not really succeed.