# Multiplication by m on elliptic curves using division polynomials

Tags: elliptic-curves, rational-functions

I'm working on ex. 3.7 (d) in Silvermans "Arithmetic on Elliptic Curves", has anyone done that proof using an elementary way and not complex analysis?

The Exercise is the following:

Let $E : y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ be an Elliptic Curve

For integers $n\ge 0$, define $\psi_n\in Z[x,y,A,B]$ by

$\psi_0  = 0$,

$\psi_1  = 1$,

$\psi_2  =  2y$,

$\psi_3  =  3x^4+6Ax^2+12Bx-A^2$,

$\psi_4  =  4y(x^6+5Ax^4+20Bx^3-5A^2x^2-4ABx-8B^2-A^3)$,

$\psi_{2m} = \frac{1}{2y}\psi_m(\psi_{m+2}\psi_{m-1}^2-\psi_{m-2}\psi_{m+1}^2)\qquad(m\ge 3),\\$

$\psi_{2m+1} = \psi_{m+2}\psi_m^3-\psi_{m-1}\psi_{m+1}^3$ ($m\ge2$)

Prove that for any Point $(x,y)$ on $E$ we have:

$[m]P   =   \Big( x - \frac{\psi_{m-1}\psi_{m+1}}{\psi_{m}^2}$,$\frac{\psi_{2m}}{2\psi_{m}^4}\Big)$ evaluated in $(x,y)$.

I've tried an induction,  proved it for $P+P$ (what is a long calculation!) and want to use the goup law on $E$ and $mP = (m-1)P+P$ to do the induction step, but i don't get anything than lousy long equations. Is there a better way using just elementary mathmatics?

Comment: I swear this is duplicate

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447672/division-polynomials-of-elliptic-curves and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492620/how-to-prove-that-multiplication-of-points-of-an-elliptic-curve-can-be-done-with (but no answer still)